# Evaluation of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string `str1 = " 2*PI"` where PI is a global string `PI = "1*pi"`

If I perform `eval(str1)` it tries to evaluate `1.*pi1.*pi`. How do I get it evaluate it as `2*(1*pi)` i.e 2 pi?

Comment: Why are you using strings to define numbers? just use `math.pi`

Comment: I suspect this question might suffer from [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), can you please provide more context? what are you  trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to process a GDML file with python. The GDML file defines PI as a constant "1*pi" and at another point refers to a variable as 2*PI

Comment: what if you evaluated - eval() - the PI string first and the inserted the evaluated in to str1 as a str through the str() command and then evaluated str1

Answer (score 3):

`eval(str1)` returns `1.*pi1.*pi` because `eval(str1)` evaluates to `2*"1*pi"` and multiplication between a string and an integer results in a repetition of the string.

Format the string directly into `str1` instead.

```
from math import pi
PI = "1*pi"
str1 = f"2*({PI})"   # or for versions < Python-3.6: "2*({})".format(PI)

print(str1)          # '2*(1*pi)'
print(eval(str1))    # 6.283185307179586
```

---

If you're not in control of `PI`, you can evaluate `PI` first, then format it into the expression.

```
eval(f"2*({eval(PI)})") # or equivalently eval("2*({})".format(eval(PI)))
```

If you're not in control of `str1` either, you can replace all `PI` tokens with its literal string value: `1*pi`.

```
eval(str1.replace('PI', PI))
```

But this doesn't handle edge cases such as `2*PIE` (if they ever appear). A more robust solution would be use a regex and surround `PI` with `\b` characters to match a full token.

```
import re
eval(re.sub(r'\bPI\b', PI, str1))
```

This appropriately excludes strings such as `2*PIZZA` or `2*API`.

Comment: Trouble is I am not in control of str1, it is defined as 2*PI in the GDML file.

Comment: @Keith Just to clarify: both `PI` and `str1` are defined in a separate file and outside your control?

Comment: Yes they are defined in a GDML file which I am trying to process. They could be defined as more or less anything

Comment: @Keith Okay thanks; I think `eval(re.sub(r'\bPI\b', PI, str1))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

what if you evaluated - eval() - the PI string first and the inserted the evaluated in to str1 as a str through the str() command and then evaluated str1

```
from math import *

PI = "1*pi"
str1 = "2*PI" 

PI = str(eval(PI)) # Turns our PI string into a number
str1 = str1.replace("PI",PI) # Sets our PI number in

print(eval(str1)) # Calculates it one last time
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6.283185307179586
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks evaluating first seems to have solved the problem.

So I now have

```
from math import pi

PI = eval("1*pi")
str1 = "2*PI"
eval(str1)
```

Which avoided any need for a replace